# Finding Java code online does not have a main type

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I am relatively new to Java. I understand some of the concepts but it is still all very new to me and am not used to the feel of it just yet. I am playing around with GUI development in Swing. However, whenever I find a chunk of code online, I ALWAYS get the error that there is no main type. When I scroll through other peoples posts who also used the code, they don't appear to be having problems with it, it runs perfectly fine for them. I am confused by this, is there something I have to setup first before using code like the example [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui)? It appears other people are able to run the code fine. No errors show up before run time. The code example I am looking at has a main type, and I still get the same error.

EDIT: The code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui DOES have a main type, but I still get the same error:

```
Editor does not contain a main type
```

Comment: Your public class name should match the name of the file it is in.

Comment: Please copy and paste the **exact** error message. By paraphrasing, you lose information that we need to help you to understand the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

When you get the error that there is no main type, it simply means that your file does not contain a class containing `main` method. The declaration is like below:

```
public class MyClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //your code
  }
}
```

It is mandatory to have exact above `main` declaration. If your class does not contain it, then probably it is being used as a library for other class.

More over your public class name `MyClass` in above case should be the name of the file. i.e. The name of the file containing the above code should be `MyClass.java`.

Comment: They might be using objects of this class but not running it directly. To be able to run a Java program it should have `main` method. Probably you can show us some sample program and we can help u with it

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does contain a main method. Scroll through until you see this `public static void main(String[] args) {`. Copy that format for your code segments in the future.

Comment: I edited the question, I noticed it does have a main type, but Eclipse still says it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes example code is not given as a complete program. Many blog authors do this in order to illustrate a concept because it will take a lot more lines of code to create a complete program that can run.

For one thing, many authors will leave out the `main()` method from an example. Since Java requires every runnable program to have a `main()` method, the author assumes that you know how to add it or will provide an example that contains the complete program that uses the snippet they discuss in the article. It sounds like the error you receive is related to this.

I hope this answers your question. If you want more specific details, please edit your question to include the *exact* error message along with the *exact* code that causes the error.